# How to test a WSDL

Tags: testing, wsdl, xsd, xml-validation

How to do WSDL testing? What is Schema Validation of WSDL. Any open source tool, or any API's available to achieve the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I want to verify WSDL file then I use Eclipse + Web Tools plugin. There is WSDL editor and validator. If I want to test WSDL both as client and server then I use soapUI. There is wsdl import and after that you can query real WebService or if you can create "mock" response. Both tools are free.

Comment: +1 soapUI. Great tool. There is also xmlspy which has a nicer interface, but it is not free.

Comment: Okay , Thank you...
Can soapUI do WSDL testing??

Comment: soapUI tests WebService: based on .wsdl file it creates queries and sends them to the WebService. It can also generate "mock" responses based on imported .wsdl. So it is more WebService tester based on .wsdl. If you want to verify .wsdl then use Web Tools Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Okay.. thank you for the informatiom. i want to verify wsdl may be i would try out the plugin .

Answer (score 0):

The WS-I organization (http://www.ws-i.org/) publishes the BSP 1.0 Testing Tools (http://www.ws-i.org/deliverables/workinggroup.aspx?wg=testingtools) which validates WSDL against the WS-I Basic Profile. This is a web service interoperability standard.

jMM