# Web Service Validator

Tags: web-services, wsdl

I am calling a web service that I think it's buggy or not following a certain standard. Is there a W3C validator that can check for this thing?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WSDL Testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129468/wsdl-testing)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, [ValidWSDL](http://www.validwsdl.com/), for example.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [WSDL Analyzer](http://wsdl-analyzer.com/) which not offers validation but also checks a WSDLs against best practices. It allows you to easily browse and inspect WSDLs and associated schema files.

Disclaimer: I am one of its developers.